# The JavaScript charts are not showing up

Tags: javascript, charts

Can anybody help me out with this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#chartContainer").dxChart({
    dataSource: [{
        st_status: "Placed Students",
        oranges: 3
    }, {
        st_status: "Higher Students",
        oranges: 2
    }, {
        st_status: "Overlap",
        oranges: 1
    }],

    series: {
        argumentField: "st_status",
        valueField: "oranges",
        name: "Series 1",
        type: "bar",
        color: "blue"
    }
});
}
            </script>
```

The charts are not showing in the webpage. Any idea what's going wrong? I am a rookie , so please forgive me if I am not asking under correct topic. Thanks!

EDIT: The error  in console says this
 Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dxChart' graph_test.php:46 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: see console and display what error it show

Comment: what browser do you use to test that? if chrome hit F12 and switch to 'console' tab and tell me if there are any errors there? if you use FF then open FireBug and do the same.

Comment: I would just use Ctrl-Shift-K. Is that Firebug?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response 
It says this..
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'dxChart' graph_test.php:46
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)...

Comment: It looks like #chartContainer is not a dxChart object. Where do you initialize #chartContainer to dxChart?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. JQuery was being included on the page a second time after the dxChart library. I removed the second script reference and everything worked fine.